# Hadith on urinating while standing

Tags: hadith

Can someone explain this hadith:

> It was narrated from Hudhaifah that: The Messenger of Allah came to
> the garbage dump of some people and he urinated on it standing up.
>
> Sunan Ibn Majah 305

Was this said before urinating while standing was abrogated?

Comment: The hadith is recorded by all six collections including by [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:224) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:273a), so maybe there should be a more better title question.

Answer (score 3):

No. Rather according to most of the jurists, urinating while standing is only makruh. And it is even not makruh when there is a valid excuse. This hadith is used as evidence for that.

> قال العلماء يكره البول قائما إلا لعذر وهي كراهة تنزيه لا تحريم
>
> The ulema said that urinating while standing is makruh except with an excuse and this is makruh tanzihi not for tahrim
>
> <sup>— [Sharah Nawawi, Sahih Muslim](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/645)</sup>

There could be various reasons for the prophet doing so. For example he could have done so to show that it was permissible. Or it could because of the filthiness of the location i.e. a garbage dump could soil his clothes and he could not find any suitable place to sit. Or it could have been that the prophet had an ache in his knee or back. Or it could have been some other reason.

> عن أبي هريرة، أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم بال قائما من جرح كان
> بمأبضه
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ urinated while standing due to an injury of the knee
>
> <sup>— [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/638), [Sunan al-Kubra Bayhaqi](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/581#p1)</sup>

Other References: [الإعلام بفوائد عمدة الأحكام](https://shamela.ws/book/13769/624) , [Mughni al-Muhtaj](https://shamela.ws/book/11444/74), [Al-Mughni Ibn Qudamah](https://shamela.ws/book/8463/119#p1)